# Flipping an one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently, I have two entities in my database. They are linked together in an one-to-many relationship as seen in the image below:

[image]

I changed my code to flip the relationship, now the diagram looks like this:

[image]

The created migration looks like this:

```cs
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Table_A_Table_B_Table_B_Id",
    table: "Table_A");

migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
    name: "IX_Table_A_Table_B_Id",
    table: "Table_A");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "Table_B_Id",
    table: "Table_A");

migrationBuilder.AddColumn<long>(
    name: "Table_A_Id",
    table: "Table_B",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0L);

var query = "UPDATE [Table_B] SET [Table_B].[Table_A_Id] = CPR.Id FROM [Table_B] PB INNER JOIN [Table_A] CPR ON PB.Id = CPR.Table_B_Id;";
migrationBuilder.Sql(query);

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Table_B_Table_A_Id",
    table: "Table_B",
    column: "Table_A_Id");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Table_B_Table_A_Table_A_Id",
    table: "Table_B",
    column: "Table_A_Id",
    principalTable: "Table_A",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

I also added an SQL-script to the migration to fill the column `TableB_Id` to not loose existing references. However, when I try to apply the migration, I get a conflict for the new foreign key:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table_B_Table_A_Table_A_Id". 
The conflict occurred in database "Evolution", table "dbo.Table_A", column 'Id'.'
```

And this is the generated query that fails:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Table_B] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_B_Table_A_Table_A_Id] 
FOREIGN KEY ([Table_A_Id]) REFERENCES [Table_A] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Is there anything else I have to do? Is this even possible within a single migration?

I've already tried to change the migration manually to first add the new column, then copy the data, delete the old and finally create the new keys and indices. This unfortunately resulted in the same error. Also first dropping the indices and then doing the rest did not work.

Comment: If you know which values `Entity_B_Id` should get, you can manually change the migration code: add the column with a default value, set the correct values, create the FK and remove the default.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that with the same result.

Comment: Please always show what you tried! It prevents people from posting the same things as an answer.

Comment: I've added more information to the question.

Comment: Then there's something wrong in "copy the data".

Comment: The error is thrown for SQL-statement generated by the line `migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey`, even if I remove the "copy the data" statement.

Comment: I mean, you don't copy the data correctly. But since you don't show what these steps look like (as in: code), I can't tell what's wrong.